# mule executing query based on condition

Tags: mule

My query goes here, what option I need to select to run as mule application.

```
 <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"  host="myhost" port="${port}" path="offcycle" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <set-variable variableName="companies" value="${companies.torun}" doc:name="Variable"/>
        <db:insert config-ref="hrlites_Configuration" doc:name="Database" >
            <db:dynamic-query>
insert into PAYRNUM (PAYGROUP,T2_PAYROLL_NUM,SEPCHK,NAME....)

        select T2_SOURCE_COMPANY,T2_PAYGROUP_TYPE,...
        from   (
        SELECT T2_SOURCE_COMPANY,T2_PAYGROUP_TYPE,PAY_END_DT,...
        FROM   CHK_STG2
        WHERE  COMPANY = #[flowVars.companies]
          AND  T2_PAYGROUP_TYPE = 'ZZ'
          AND  PAY_END_DT =  '30/JUN/2013'
        ORDER BY PAY_END_DT,
              CASE WHEN T2_INVOICE_NBR LIKE 'IN%' then 1
                   WHEN T2_INVOICE_NBR LIKE 'CM%' then 2                   
                   ELSE 3
              END
        ) a,
        (
        select t2_invoice_nbr, OFF_CYCLE, CASE When b.OFF_CYCLE ='N' THEN 0
                    ELSE rownum
                    END as T2_PAYROLL_NUM
        from   (
                select distinct t2_invoice_nbr, OFF_CYCLE
                from   (
                        SELECT T2_INVOICE_NBR,...
                        FROM   PS_T2_INV_CHK_STG2
                        WHERE  COMPANY = #[flowVars.companies]
                          AND  T2_PAYGROUP_TYPE = 'ZZ'
                          AND  PAY_END_DT =  '30/JUN/2013'
                        ORDER BY PAY_END_DT,
                            CASE WHEN T2_INVOICE_NBR LIKE 'IN%' then 1
                                  WHEN T2_INVOICE_NBR LIKE 'CM%' then 2                                 
                                  ELSE 3
                            END
                      )
               ) b
        ) bb
    where a.t2_invoice_nbr = bb.t2_invoice_nbr      
    ORDER BY PAY_END_DT,
        CASE WHEN T2_INVOICE_NBR LIKE 'IN%' then 1            
             ELSE 5
        END;
        </db:dynamic-query>
        </db:insert>        
    </flow>
```

1) If run the query, it executes fine in db. but If i run in mule flow I am getting following error:

```
2015-01-28 17:18:48 ERROR DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy:337 - 
********************************************************************************
Message               : ORA-00911: invalid character
 (java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException). Message payload is of type: String
Type                  : org.mule.api.MessagingException
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
Payload               : /offcycle
SQL Code              : 911
JavaDoc               : http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MessagingException.html
SQL State             : 42000
********************************************************************************
Exception stack is:
1. ORA-00911: invalid character
(SQL Code: 911, SQL State: + 42000) (java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException)
  oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping:91 (null)
2. ORA-00911: invalid character
 (java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException). Message payload is of type: String (org.mule.api.MessagingException)
  org.mule.module.db.internal.processor.AbstractDbMessageProcessor:81
********************************************************************************
Root Exception stack trace:
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00911: invalid character
```

I have selected type as  parameter instead of Dynamic, but no use.

2) How to display the executed query in console, so that I will come to know the parameter passed and final query.

Comment: Seems like there are a syntax error in your query, may be produced by the replacement of MEL expressions. As you are using a dynamic query (and so the MEL expressions are replaced inline) I recommend you to use a "Parse template" transformer just before the `db:insert`, setting the query with MEL expressions as the template, and then use a logger to see the result. This could help you to figure out what´s wrong. HTH, Marcos.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are using a flowvar in your query. Are you defining the companies flowvar before the query execution? If not your query would be like

..
WHERE  COMPANY = 
AND 
...

which is going to be invalida.

You can use the Mule debugger and add a breakpoint at the database Message Processor to see the values of the properties and variables.

If after executing the query you want to log the query result you can try to add an object-to-string transformer and then a logger with the #[payload] expression in it.

Comment: nothing wrong in getting the flowVars values. I tried same query by hardcoding the values, gets same error.